# Solr - Nested Edismax Query

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using Solr (with [pySolr](https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr)) to search products in my database, returning products, facets and facet.pivots:

```
result = solr.search(query_s, **{
    'rows': '24',
    'sort': formatted_sort,
    'facet': 'on',
    'facet.limit': '-1',
    'facet.mincount': '1',
    'facet.field': ['gender', 'material'],
    'facet.pivot': 'brand,series',
    'fq': '-in_stock:(0 OR 99 OR 100 OR 101)'
    })
```

The `query_s` selects specific fields, for example: `brand:Target AND gender:Men's`.

I would like to combine the above query with a DisMax query which will allow me to combine the above query with a full text search over specified fields. I found an [article](https://lucidworks.com/2009/03/31/nested-queries-in-solr/) which demonstrates nested queries. I have tried to implement something like this:

```
q: "gender:* AND _query_:"{!edismax qf=brand series}Summer""
```

For some reason 'Target' will return results for Target brand shirts, but only with correct capitalization. 'Summer' which is a series of Target, won't return any results. Why am I not seeing a list of docs ordered by relevancy?

Am I overcomplicating things  by using Dismax altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dismax parsers are useful for making sense of more "natural" queries, i.e. queries where the user is used to just type what they're looking for, and how most search engines work.

In your case it sounds like `brand:Target AND gender:Men's` are filters for which documents should be shown, while the query is the part that the user has typed. Usually you'll want to have the filters in `fq` as they don't affect score (i.e. they're exact values matching a field value), and the query in `q`.

I assume that `Summer` is what the user would have typed into your search box, which would give you:

```
q=Summer&defType=edismax&qf=series
```

But this assumes that the `series` field is defined as a text field that has an analyzer attached, so that the values are lowercased and split appropriately.

If you also have a `description` field you'd like to search, you can do:

```
q=Summer&defType=edismax&qf=series^20 description
```

.. which would search for `Summer` in both the `series` and `description` fields, but give 20 times more weight to a hit in the `series` field. This is a good way to naturally boost documents that match more exact data in your documents. If you also include the `brand` field, you'd be able to let your users search for "target summer" and similar queries.